# find tag values from Xml format in table

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmp
            (
              ProcedureID INT ,
              ProcedureName NVARCHAR(100) ,
              OriginalVariableName NVARCHAR(200) ,
              StatementNumber INT ,
              RuleStatementID INT ,
              StatementXML NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
              CountOrg INT DEFAULT 0 ,
              [Count] INT DEFAULT 0 ,
              VarID INT ,
              ParentID INT ,
              ParentName NVARCHAR(100) ,
              StatementType NVARCHAR(20) ,
              [Type] NVARCHAR(3) ,
              xml XML ,
              str NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
              Opindex INT ,    

            )
```

I fetch date from another table and insert into above table

In StatementXML  column have xml values same as belows

CUSTOMER-MASTER-  RECORDXYZABCaabb

I want to find values of tag aa and bb, It may be blank or some values

if I found values in both tag then I want to update Type column of #tmp table

I want to find values from   tag and   tags

Like --
ID , column,    value
1 ,  ,
2 ,  XYZ  ,     aa
3 ,  ABC ,      bb
....
....
....
in a table format

how can I do this in store procedure.

Please help here.
as per generate values I want to update some values in others table.

I also check below method for this but I not get values

```
declare @x xml = '<INSERT STATEMENTNUMBER="1595" CURSORNAME="" FILENAME="" INPUTTYPE="" RESPCODE=""><INSERTSTATEMENT>
<TABLES><TABLE><NAME>VIDEO-MASTER-RECORD</NAME><ALIAS></ALIAS></TABLE>
</TABLES><JOINS><JOIN><TYPE></TYPE><TABLE><NAME></NAME><ALIAS></ALIAS></TABLE></JOIN></JOINS>
<COLUMNS><COLUMN><NAME>VM-VIDEO-NUMBER</NAME></COLUMN><COLUMN><NAME>VM-TITLE</NAME></COLUMN><COLUMN><NAME>VM-MEDIA-TYPE</NAME>
</COLUMN><COLUMN><NAME>VM-STATUS</NAME></COLUMN><COLUMN><NAME>VM-CUSTOMER-NUMBER</NAME></COLUMN><COLUMN><NAME>VM-DATE-OUT</NAME></COLUMN></COLUMNS>
<VALUES>VIDEO-MASTER-RECORD</VALUES></INSERTSTATEMENT></INSERT>'




select   @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER, 
 @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[1]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1' INTO aa
Insert into aa  select  @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER, @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[2]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[2]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1'       
Insert into aa select  @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER, @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[3]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[3]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1' 
Insert into aa select  @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER, @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[4]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[4]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1' 
Insert into aa select  @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER, @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[5]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[5]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1' 
Insert into aa select  @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER, @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[6]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[6]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1'  
Insert into aa select  @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER, @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[7]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[7]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1'  
Insert into aa select  @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER,  @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[8]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[8]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1'  
Insert into aa select  @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER, @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[9]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[9]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1'  
Insert into aa select  @x.value('(/INSERT/@STATEMENTNUMBER)[1]', 'int')  as STATEMENTNUMBER, @x.value('(//COLUMN/NAME)[10]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'column1' ,@x.value('(//VALUES)[10]', 'varchar(max)')  AS 'value1'
```

I got result in aa table as

```
STATEMENTNUMBER column1    value1
1595    VM-TITLE       NULL
1595    VM-MEDIA-TYPE       NULL
1595    VM-STATUS       NULL
1595    VM-CUSTOMER-NUMBER   NULL
1595    VM-DATE-OUT      NULL
1595    NULL                 NULL
1595    NULL                 NULL
1595    NULL                 NULL
1595    NULL                 NULL
1595    VM-VIDEO-NUMBER VIDEO-MASTER-RECORD
```

so I need to update on value as per last row because both column have values VM-VIDEO-NUMBER    and VIDEO-MASTER-RECORD, I want to ignore or delete rows which column1  or value1 have null values
Please advice

Comment: you could try using patindex and substring but you'll have to play around with those if the values you have are variable length

Comment: HOW CAN I put variable in below query  ---  select @x.value('(/COLUMNS/COLUMN/NAME)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), I want put variable on place of 1  [1] and insert data into a temp table , when I put variable then its shows error like ---   The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.

Comment: this doesn't make sense. if you want to have [1] be a parameter why not just have that entire string '/COLUMNS/COLUMN/NAME/[1]' be a parameter instead and declare it elsewhere. -- please clarify because what you are asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: In above code , I just put values into variable because I don't know that how much times <name> tag in column value and I want all values into a another table so I can check that if name tag and value tag have value then I will update status in another table, means if each name tag have values and same value tag have value , then I can do action another no need to do any action

Comment: you need to give a better example because your logic isn't making sense. can you edit your question to have a sample table with sample data that you are querying. and show what you want your end result to be.